# Compare item to list of items, excluding the item being compared

Tags: c#, list, loops, logic

I have a list of items lets say | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | I want to take 1 and compare it to the rest of the list, but I do not wish for 1 to compare to itself. After 1 has compared to the rest of the list I think want to pop 1 back into the list and then take 2 out and compare to the rest of list this time including 1. This is what I have tried. The problem here is when I iterate the first time through it works perfect because the first iterate starts at 0 and compares starting at 1, but then once it loops past the 0 index it will start comparing against it self causing problems. Any help would be awesome. I know this is just a logic thing I have to figure out but I am getting a little lost.

Here is what I have tried

```
        if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int fileBuffer = 0; fileBuffer < RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count; fileBuffer++)
        {
            for (int fileList = 1; fileList < RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count; fileList++)
            {
                if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[fileBuffer] != RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[fileList])
                {
                    if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[fileBuffer].GetName() == RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[fileList].GetName())
                    {
                        lbl_message.Text = "There where duplicates files found please check the files and try again";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //do other stuffs
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 1)
{
    for (int fileBuffer = 0; fileBuffer < RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count-1; fileBuffer++)
    {
        for (int fileList = fileBuffer + 1; fileList < RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count; fileList++)
        {
            if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[fileBuffer] != RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[fileList])
            {
//....
```

Comment: Checking this out now. I will let you know how it works and marked Answered. Thanks for the fast reply ^_^

Comment: What I need to accomplish is 1 gets pulled and checked against the rest of the items then 2 gets pulled and checked against the rest (including 1) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | . So its like I pull 1 out and compare against 2345 then I pull 2 out and compare against 1345 then 3 and compare 1245 then 4 and compare 1235 then 5 and compare 1234.

Currently this approach doesn't check the last item which I still want to preform. Even though by going through the list it already checked all the items I still want to have the last item check against the rest also.

Comment: @NitroFrost in the first loop, 1 has been already compared with 2, but you still compare them again in the second loop? That's strange.

Comment: Yea I agree. I am going through my logic now. I think I fixed it. Why would I want to compare the last item if it has already been compared to every possible item.

Comment: I went through and fixed my logic of what I was doing after I did the compare and it worked fine. What I ended up doing was I created a int buffer = 0; and while it was looping for the compare if it found a compare it just added to that int and breaks and then goes to another conditional that checks what buffer is set to and if its = 0 then it will do the logic if not it will end the function and show an error. I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find duplicates? LINQ would simplify it enormously:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var dups = list.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
foreach (var dup in dups)
{
    int i = dup.Key;
    int count = dup.Count();
}
```

That works also with your [`UploadedFileCollection`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-manipulating-files.html) (with the help of `Cast` since it only implements the non-generic [`CollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a03ybbb) class):

```
var dupFiles = uploadedFiles.Cast<UploadedFile>()
    .GroupBy(f => f.GetName())
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
foreach (var dupFile in dupFiles)
{
    string fileName = dupFile.Key;
    int count = dupFile.Count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for taking the time and answering. I haven't done any work with LINQ but I will look at what you have show here closer and see what I can do with it. This example looks like it could really help me in cleaning my code and using better practices. I have a lot of learning to do and I appreciate you added to my list of things I need to look up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't using your code but the simple concept of comparing each item with every item but it's self is there, good luck.

```
def search(alist):
    for anitem in alist:
        for anotheritem in alist:
            if alist.index(anitem) == alist.index(anotheritem):
                pass
            else:
                Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead to delete and add the item from the list you could use Object.ReferenceEquals to know if it is the same File instance or not:

Try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<File> FileList = new List<File>();
        FileList.Add(new File { FullPath = "File1" });
        FileList.Add(new File { FullPath = "File2" });
        FileList.Add(new File { FullPath = "File3" });
        FileList.Add(new File { FullPath = "File4" });
        FileList.Add(new File { FullPath = "File5" });
        //FileList.Add(new FileName { FullPath = "File5" });

        foreach (File SourceFile in FileList) 
        {
            foreach (File TestFile in FileList) 
            {
                if (SourceFile.GetName() == TestFile.GetName() && !(Object.ReferenceEquals(SourceFile, TestFile)))
                {
                    var lbl_message = "There where duplicates files found please check the files and try again";
                }
                else 
                {
                    //another stuff
                }
            }                    
        }
    }
}

public class File
{
    public string FullPath;

    public string GetName()
    {
        return FullPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to explore Object.ReferenceEquals more. Thanks for this example to go off of though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a linq query for that:

```
    var duplicatesFiles = from file in FileList 
                     group file by file.GetName() into groupedbyname
                     where groupedbyname.Count() > 1
                     select groupedbyname.Count();

    bool thereAreDuplicates = duplicatesFiles.Count() > 0;
```